# Return all values from array in lowercase using for loop instead of map

Tags: javascript

```
var sorted = words.map(function(value) {
    return value.toLowerCase();
}).sort();
```

This code returns all values from words array in lowercase and sorts them, but I wanna do the same with a `for` loop but I can't.

I tried:

```
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  sorted = [];
  sorted.push(words[i].toLowerCase());
};
```

Comment: A suggestion for future reference: When you update the code in a question as a result of one of the answers, please don't edit the original (incorrect) code. Instead, keep that original code unchanged and add a new section to the end of the question like, "I modified the code as suggested in XYZ's answer, but it still doesn't work. Here's the new code: ..." This way the question and answers will make much more sense for future visitors.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With arrays, the `+=` operator does not do what you expect - it calls `.toString` on the array and concatenates them. Instead, you want to use the [array `push` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
var sorted = [];
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    sorted.push(words[i].toLowerCase());
}
sorted.sort();
```

Comment: I updated the code a bit (please see), but now it returns only 1 element, not all of them.

Comment: You have your `sorted = [];` inside the loop - where it overwrites the array with a new one repeatedly (and only the last one, with the last item, will be returned). See my answer for how the code should look.

Comment: Yea, I compared your code and mine and realized that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 76):

You can also now achieve this very simply by using an arrow function and the `map()` method of the Array:

```js
var words = ['Foo','Bar','Fizz','Buzz'].map(v => v.toLowerCase());
console.log(words);
```

Note that `map()` will only work in browsers which support ES2015. In other words, anything except IE8 and lower.

Similarly, arrow functions will not work at all in IE. For a legacy browser safe version you would need to use an anonymous function:

```js
var words = ['Foo','Bar','Fizz','Buzz'].map(function(v) {
  return v.toLowerCase();
});
console.log(words);
```

Comment: And if you want to use that as a function, use function arrayToLowerCase(array) {
            return array.map(function(v) {
                return v.toLowerCase();
            });
        }

Comment: Array.prototype.toLowerCase = function(){return this.map(v => v.toLowerCase())}

Answer (score 47):

push is overused.

```
for (var i = 0, L=words.length ; i < L; i++) {
  sorted[i]=words[i].toLowerCase();
}
```

If you want *fast* and have a very large array of words, call toLowerCase once-

```
sorted=words.join('|').toLowerCase().split('|');
```

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a later answer but I've found a prettier and simpler way:

```
yourArray = ['this', 'iS an', 'arrAy'];
console.log(yourArray); // ["this", "iS an", "arrAy"]

yourLowerArray = yourArray.toLocaleString().toLowerCase().split(',');
console.log(yourLowerArray); //["this", "is an", "array"]
```

Explaining what this does:

`.toLocaleString()` -> transform the array into a string separated by commas.

`.toLowerCase()` -> convert that string to lower case.

`.split(',')` -> convert the string in lower case back to an array.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: note that `toLocaleString()` might not always return a comma separated string

Comment: `.join(',')` would reliably use a comma instead.

Answer (score 0):

`toLowerCase()` is function, you should write `()` after it

Answer (score 0):

The toLowerCase method is not being called in your code, only referenced. Change your line in the loop to:

```
sorted += words[i].toLowerCase();
```

Add () to call the method.

Complete working code:

```
var words = ["FOO", "BAR"];
var sorted = [];

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        sorted.push(words[i].toLowerCase());
};

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're declaring `sorted` as an array. If so use the `push` method rather than `+=`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  sorted.push(words[i].toLowerCase());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words.forEach(function (item, index) {
    words[index] = item.toLowerCase();
});
```